# how to put a <?php foreach?> in a column based grid

Tags: php, css

I'm  trying to put the output of a query, in php, in a column based grid. I was trying to get a pinterest like effect with four columns, where every post has a different height, but where they all have the same width.

If I try using `display: grid;`, I'll get a single column with all the posts, because the foreach will just dump it all there.

if i try using `display: inline-grid;` it becomes a row based grid, and the result isn't exactly pretty.

**php code**

```
class Post{
 public static function getAll()
    {
        $conn = Db::getInstance();
        $result = $conn->query('SELECT posts.*,users.firstname,users.lastname, users.picture FROM posts,users WHERE posts.user_id=users.id ');
        return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __CLASS__);
    }
}
```

**html code**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="post">
    <article >
          <img src="<?php echo $post->picture; ?>" class="profilepic">
          <p class="name"> <?php echo $post->firstname.' '.$post->lastname; ?> </p>
          <p> <?php echo $post->date_created; ?> </p>
          <img src="<?php echo $post->image; ?>" alt="">
          <p> <?php echo $post->description; ?> </p>
          <a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $post->id; ?>">More</a>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**css code**

```
div.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could try to write the proper markup first (by hand, without any PHP!) and then split it into the relevant parts to make the output dynamic

Comment: Do you mean divide the posts in columns manually? if so, I've been thinking something along this line as well

Comment: @Wendelin and @ Jorre thank you for your effort. I tried a couple of things that you suggested and a couple of other things that i found online. the result isn't really what i wanted but it'll do for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your post is placed around your `<div class="post">`. Currently you are creating a new `<div class="grid-container">` on every loop iteration.

Also, instead of using the css property `grid-column` please use `grid-template-columns` as @Wendelin has shown above in the code snippet.

If that doesn't work, please paste a dump of your rendered HTML and CSS here.

Comment: so i tried your suggestions and it didn't change anything... i'm a bit new to stack overflow so i didn't really get what you meant with the paste & dump

Comment: @ Jorre thank you for your effort. I tried a couple of things that you suggested and a couple of other things that i found online. the result isn't really what i wanted but it'll do for now

Answer (score 0):

Your css is wrong `grid-column` specifies in which column an item should be. What you want is `grid-template-columns`

```
div.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
```

also instead of using `25%` you can use `1fr`. [Read more](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/).

Basically `fr` stands for fraction. You define `1fr` four times so together there are 4 fractions. 
Then it divides the specified fractions by the total fractions and converts it to percent.

Example:

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` = `grid-template-columns: 1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4` = `grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%`

`grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 2fr 3fr` = `grid-template-columns: 2/8 1/8 2/8 3/8` = `grid-template-columns: 25% 12.5% 25% 37.5%`

```css
div.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.post {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <article>
      Some content
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this just gets me the same result. All the posts are displayed in a single column

Comment: @MargotVanOvertveldt Pleas run the code snippet. Unless your browser does not support css grids this does work.

Comment: the code snippet works, but not when implemented in my code. I think the html just doesn't know where to start the next column and thus just puts it all in one

Comment: @MargotVanOvertveldt also check my answer below — there's two things you should focus on: 1) your loop is rendering multiple grids instead of one grid and 2) your CSS properties aren't used correctly to set up a grid with multiple columns.